# How do I manage my test data as an Object[][] reading from a YAML file?

Tags: java, selenium, testng, yaml, dataprovider

This is my YAML file:

```
case 1: ["Jackson","23","Salt Lake City"]
case 2: ["Rachael","35","San Diego"]
#this will keep building and possibly have 1000 rows or so
```

I want these all into a 2D array like this:

```
{{"Jackson","23","Salt Lake City"},
{"Rachael","35","San Diego"}}
```

Basically I want to use these 2 sets of data in a TestNG data provider.

So I will create a DataProvider method which will return this 2D object. And the test method using this data provider will iterate through it. First it will take the "Jackson" data. The second round will take "Rachael" data.

I have used Jackson for serialization before like so:

```
public class TestCase {
  @JsonProperty("Test")
  private List<String> data;

  public List<String> getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public void setData(List<String> data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

But for this to work my YAML should be like so:

```
Test: ["Jackson","23","Salt Lake City"]
Test: ["Rachael","35","San Diego"]
```

But then the ObjectMapper only reads the last row. In this case the "Rachael" row.

Actually I don't care about "case 1" or "case 2". I want to write a method which will return an Object[][] containing the following:

```
{{"Jackson","23","Salt Lake City"},
{"Rachael","35","San Diego"}}
```

How do I achieve this inside my method?

I want this method to iterate through each row of the YAML file and put each row into an arraylist which stays inside the Object[][].

If you guys have better ways to manage test data using YAML please let me know.

Comment: Can't you use FileReader/Scanner class to read the file and read fule one at a time and create `object[][]` array based on it ?.

Comment: That can surely be done. That is the first brute force method I used. But I specifically want to achieve this using serialization. I want to achieve this using some form of serialization using Jackson or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don’t need keys (case 1, case 2)  for your data, you can simplify your Yaml file
just change to

`- ["Jackson","23","Salt Lake City"]
- ["Rachael","35","San Diego"]`

then read as ArrayList by using [SnakeYAML](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml) library and convert to Object[][]
You can try the next snippet in you DataProvider method

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("path_to_your_file"));
ArrayList<ArrayList> list = (ArrayList<ArrayList>) new Yaml().load(input);

Object[][] data = list.stream()
        .map(dataSet -> dataSet.toArray())
        .toArray(Object[][]::new);
```

Handling test data is a common problem for automation QA’s. Choosing YAML files is already a good decision. We use [Selenium Automation Bundle](https://github.com/sysgears/selenium-automation-bundle) as it has already integrated a solution for test data. There is no description of the solution in Readme, but here it is an example of a [test](https://github.com/sysgears/selenium-automation-bundle/blob/master/src/test/groovy/com/sysgears/seleniumbundle/tests/demo/Tools.groovy), and here it is an example of a file with test [data](https://github.com/sysgears/selenium-automation-bundle/blob/master/src/test/resources/data/google/test_data.yml) which are enough to start using it. Though the bundle uses Groovy, you can write Java code in groovy classes without any doubts.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I had never heard of Selenium Automation Bundle before. Cloned it and currently reading through it. No problem with groovy as I can interpret it into Java without issues. Thanks for the help.